# Anime short about two girls shooting each other with guns from their mouths

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha, short-film

I saw an anime short some years ago on YouTube. I can't find it anywhere. The things that I remember are:

- The "protagonist" is a girl with brown hair tied up and yellow clothes.  She is a robot that is controlled by a group of some kind of small animal (I don’t remember what kind.)
- It began with her waking up, the animals beginning to control her to get up.
- There was her friend (well, ex-friend) who had black hair and dark clothes and was a robot too, controlled by little bunnies. It seemed these bunnies killed one of the little animals of the brown-haired girl, so they started fighting, making the two girls start shooting each other with guns from their mouths.
- The animals on the head of the girl spoke. I don't remember any other character speaking, maybe the mother of the protagonist saying to the girl she was late?
- There was a guy too, it seems the protagonist liked him because of a photo she was holding on one part.
- The title was probably in English, since there were so many people writing about the story being a representation of a promise that was broken that made three friends fight.
- The protagonist killed the guy too, he was a ''ikemen''. I remember the animal inside the protagonist head saying something about it.

More things happen after that, but I don't remember so well.

Comment: Seryu from _Akame ga Kill_ has a gun coming out of her mouth and relies on her robot-dog-Imperial arm to transform. Don't remember any bunnies though...

Comment: I don't think it is, the style is way too diferent , and is more like a music video (?). I think is only a animation project that i saw.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't think either. Say, could you take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? There's also [this one on anime-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/98028) - every detail could help identifying it :)

Comment: Hopefully, you can remember if the title/description of the video is in English/Japanese/another language? The duration of the video (i.e. less than 5 minutes)? And either it's a music video or just an indie anime? Also, "some years" = around what year? If there's a dialog of the character in the video (also possibly in what language?)

Comment: I guess only the animal that was giving orders to the rest of the crew (that was piloting the protagonist) spoke more , the other characters didn't say a word. (btw sorry for my english)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for *I Can Friday By Day!*:

It features all the things you mention - a brown-haired girl girl controlled by small animals (squirrels), another girl controlled by rabbits, a boy, and a fight between them.

It was one of the films from the short-film project Japan Animator Expo; you can find some details on the film's creators and such [here](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-04-20/19th-animator-expo-short-is-kazuya-tsurumaki-hajime-ueda-i-can-friday-by-day/.87330) if you're interested.

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU FOUND IT !

Comment: @Miss_kono Happy I could help!